# Intuitive thinking of the mean of Exponential distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

While doing problems in a competitive exam I encountered the Exponential distribution that is whose PDF is $f(x) = \frac{1}{\theta} e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$ , and I needed the expectation of this $X$ following exponential distribution,I knew that it is either $\theta$ or $\frac{1}{\theta}$.

I had to do the integration $\int_{0}^{\infty}x f(x) dx$ in order to get $\theta$ which may affect some time.

Yes,one should get that by practice but I was thinking is there any intuitive way of seeing and telling that the mean can only be $\theta$ and it cannot be $\frac{1}{\theta}$ for sure without performing the integration?.

As in a similar way like when we see numbers 3,4,5 we think of right-angled triangle or Pythagoras theorem!, perhaps a bad example.

Comment: This is not the Beta distribution, but the Exponential distribution.

Comment: Yes,my bad did an edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is not what is typically called a [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). It is an [exponential distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)

To answer your question, the way I'd remember is a dimensional analysis approach you might see in physics and engineering. Since $x/\theta$ appears in the exponential in $\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}$, it is unitless, so we see that $\theta$ has the same units as $X.$ Thus we know that it must be $E(X) = \theta,$ since $E(X)$ obviously has the same units as $X.$

Another way to see it is that if we set $\theta$ larger, the exponential $e^{-x/\theta}$ decays slower, so the mean will be larger. Thus we know that $E(X)$ must vary positively with $\theta,$ so $E(X) = \theta.$

Comment: Nice, If $e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$ decays slower,then how can we see that the mean will be larger?

Comment: Which of these two distributions looks like it has a larger mean? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Bexp(-x),+exp(-x%2F5)%2F5%7D,+x+%3D+0+to+10

Comment: For an exponential, slower decay = more mass on the larger numbers =  higher average value.